# Hide cardViews after clicked on button from another cardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, cardview

In my scenario if I click on a expanded card from `card_1` then all other cards should be invisible. Also, can I change the positions of the card runtime so it can move 2nd card on the position of the first and it will expand to full screen so there will be no need to hide other cards.

Please check the attached image.

[image]

```
public class DashboardMarketAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_TOP_MENU = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_MOVERS = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_DERIVATIVES = 2;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_NEWS = 3;
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] menuItems;

    public DashboardMarketAdapter(Context context, String[] menuItems) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.menuItems = menuItems;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_TOP_MENU:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_top_view, parent, false);
                return new TopMenuViewHolder(v, parent.getContext());

            case VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_MOVERS:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_market_movers, parent, false);
                return new MarketMoversViewHolder(v, parent.getContext());

            case VIEW_TYPE_DERIVATIVES:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_market_derivatives, parent, false);
                return new MarketDerivativesViewHolder(v);

            case VIEW_TYPE_NEWS:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_top_news, parent, false);
                return new TopNewsViewHolder(v);

            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    /**
     * The length of the string array will tell recycler view the count of the card views.
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return menuItems.length;
    }

    /**
     * @param position this will return the view of the card according to the position of the card.
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_TOP_MENU:
                return VIEW_TYPE_TOP_MENU;
            case VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_MOVERS:
                return VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_MOVERS;
            case VIEW_TYPE_DERIVATIVES:
                return VIEW_TYPE_DERIVATIVES;
            case VIEW_TYPE_NEWS:
                return VIEW_TYPE_NEWS;
            default:
                return 0;

        }

    }

    /**
     * This view holder is holding the view of topmost card,
     * which contains tab and viewpager.
     */
    static class TopMenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @InjectView(R.id.pager)
        ViewPager top_view_pager;
        @InjectView(R.id.tabs)
        DashboardSlidingTabLayout top_view_tabs;
        @InjectView(R.id.expand)
        Button btnExpand;
        @InjectView(R.id.card_view)
        CardView cardView;

        private DashboardTabAdapter adapter;
        private CharSequence Titles[];
        private int NumberOfTabs;
        int pos;
        static int setView = 0;
        int minHeight;

        public static final int TOP_VIEW = 0;
        public static final int INDICES = 1;
        public static final int COMMODITY = 2;
        public static final int CURRENCY = 3;

        public TopMenuViewHolder(View itemView, final Context context) {

            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);
            Titles = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_dashboard_tab_menu);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("setView", setView);
            NumberOfTabs = Titles.length;
            adapter = new DashboardTabAdapter(((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, NumberOfTabs, bundle);
            top_view_pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            top_view_tabs.setViewPager(top_view_pager);
            /**
             * Here visibility of Expand button is decided upon the tab selected.
             */
            top_view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    pos = position;
                    if (position > 0) {
                        btnExpand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        initializeTab();
                    } else if (position == 0) {
                        btnExpand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        collapseView();
                    }
                }

            });

            /**
             * This will be used to give initial height for the top card.
             */
            cardView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    cardView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    minHeight = cardView.getHeight();

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = cardView.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.height = minHeight;
                    cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    return true;
                }
            });
            /**
             * Here you can get the height of the screen
             */
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            DisplayMetrics dimension = new DisplayMetrics();
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dimension);
            final int height = dimension.heightPixels;

            /**
             * Here you can add logic for expanding a card.
             */
            btnExpand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("Dashboard", "Current Fragment" + top_view_pager.getCurrentItem());
                    new ChildRecyclerView(context, true);
                    new ParentRecyclerView(context, false);
                    toggleCardViewnHeight(height);


                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * This method will toggle expand and collapse of card view.
         */

        private void toggleCardViewnHeight(int height) {
            int ViewMinHeight = minHeight;
            if (cardView.getHeight() == ViewMinHeight) {
                // expand

                expandView(height);

            } else {
                // collapse
                collapseView();

            }
        }

        /**
         * This method will initialize tab adapter depending upon the page selected.
         */

        public void initializeTab() {
            switch (top_view_pager.getCurrentItem()) {
                case INDICES:
                    ((IndicesFragment) adapter.getRegisteredFragment(INDICES)).initUI();
                    break;
                case COMMODITY:
                    ((CommodityDashboardFragment) adapter.getRegisteredFragment(COMMODITY)).initUI();
                    break;
                case CURRENCY:
                    ((CurrencyDashboardFragment) adapter.getRegisteredFragment(CURRENCY)).initUI();
                    break;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Collapse View Animation
         */
        public void collapseView() {
            BaseFragment.isExpanded = 0;
            ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(cardView.getMeasuredHeightAndState(),
                    minHeight);
            anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = cardView.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.height = val;
                    cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }
            });
            anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    initializeTab();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });

            anim.start();
        }

        /**
         * Expand View Animation
         */
        public void expandView(int height) {
            BaseFragment.isExpanded = 1;

            ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(cardView.getMeasuredHeightAndState(),
                    height);
            anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = cardView.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.height = val;
                    cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }
            });
            anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    initializeTab();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
            anim.start();

        }


    }

    /**
     * This view holder is holding the view of MarketMovers card,
     */
    static class MarketMoversViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @InjectView(R.id.btnExpand)
        Button btnExpand;
        @InjectView(R.id.card_view)
        CardView cardView;
        @InjectView(R.id.relativeLayout)
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        int height;
        String []menuItem={"MARKET MOVERS","DERIVATIVES","TOP NEWS"};
        public MarketMoversViewHolder(View itemView, final Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);

            relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    height = relativeLayout.getHeight();
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = cardView.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.height = 400;
                    cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }

            });
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            DisplayMetrics dimension = new DisplayMetrics();
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dimension);
            int width = dimension.widthPixels;
            final int screenHeight = dimension.heightPixels;
            final int fullHeight = screenHeight - 400;
            btnExpand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    toggleCardViewnHeight(fullHeight);
                    DashboardMarketAdapter DM =new DashboardMarketAdapter(context,menuItem);
                    DM.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });


        }

        private void toggleCardViewnHeight(int height) {
            int ViewMinHeight = 400;
            if (cardView.getHeight() == ViewMinHeight) {
                // expand
                ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(cardView.getMeasuredHeightAndState(),
                        height);
                anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                        int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = cardView.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.height = val;
                        cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    }
                });
                anim.start();
            } else {
                // collapse
                ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(cardView.getMeasuredHeightAndState(),
                        ViewMinHeight);
                anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                        int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = cardView.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.height = val;
                        cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    }
                });
                anim.start();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This view holder is holding the view of Derivatives card,
     */
    private class MarketDerivativesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public MarketDerivativesViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This view holder is holding the view of NEWS card,
     */
    private class TopNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TopNewsViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }
}
```